# Input value of a cloned div not changing or firing events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a mock hidden div that I edit, clone and show to users. In this div is an input for which I set the value attribute using jQuery (tried with probably all methods). After I generate the new div and show it to users, the input does not fire any kind of events (focus, focusout, change) neither does the value of input change in HTML.
What am I missing or doing wrong?

Edit (code): HTML

```
<div class="item-wrapper" id="mock-item">
  <div class="item-img"></div>
  <div class="item-primary">
    <p class="item-name">Foo Bar</p>
    <input type="text" class="set-amount">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("div.item-wrapper").click((e) => {
    let item_id = e.currentTarget.id
    let itemDetails = {
        item_name: $(`#${item_id} .item.name`).text(),
        suggested_amount: $(`#${item_id} #item-amount`).text(),
        icon_url: $(`#${item_id} .item.big`).attr("style"),
    }
    $(".item-img", tmp).attr("style", itemDetails.icon_url)
    $("#mock-item .item-name").text(itemDetails.item_name)
    $("#mock-item .set-amount")[0].setAttribute("value", itemDetails.suggested_amont)

    $("#mock-item").clone().removeAttr("id").appendTo(".item-wrapper").show()
})
```

Comment: We can't help you without you sharing your code that is relevant to your question. Please add your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloning an element removes all the event listeners from it. If you would like to listen for all event listeners on elements with a given selector, you can use jQuery's `.on`:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".class", function () {
  const $this = $(this);
});
```

You could also set the `withDataAndEvents` parameter on `.clone` to true: `.clone(true)`.